# in rails tinymce have problem showing the image instead of that show a long string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, image, tinymce

i recendly add a gem tinymce and i did all the step that the [page](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tinymce-rails/4.3.0) tell me but the result was a loooong string and i really don t know why, here i put my codes:

i create a tinymce.yml file with this:

```
default:
  plugins:
    - image
    - link

alternate:
  selector: textarea.table-editor
  toolbar: styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | table
  plugins:
    - table
```

then i add the following sentence in applications.js:

```
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.validate
//= require.validate.additional-methods
//= require tinymce
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

S(document).ready(function(){
  S('#new_user').validate({
    rules {
      'user[email]': {
        required:true,
        email:true,
      },
      'user[password]': {
        required:tree,
        minlength:1
      },
      'user[password_confirmation]': {
        required:true,
        equalTo: '#user_password',
      }
    },
  })
})
```

and in the view i put the following:

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, id: :publication_content, :rows => 10, :cols => 10,
     :class => "tinymce" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
  <%= tinymce %>
<% end %>
```

in all the case here is my database:

```
class CreatePublications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :publications do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :city, foreign_key: true
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and this is what is showing me the page instead of the link and the imagen:

[image]

so i really don t know what can i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `.html_safe` on strings with html tags that you want to be HTML tags on the rendered view, otherwise ActionView scapes the tags and the browser shows them as text. You are not showing the view with the problem though, but a `.html_safe` on both lines should work.